# Cypress - How to reload the page after a test has run without triggering the test to re-run?

Tags: cypress

Hey I'm wondering if there is a way to refresh the page after a cypress test has finished running (or has been stopped) without triggering the whole test to restart.

I know from within a test itself I could use `cy.reload()` but I'm talking about a way to do it from the gui or the chrome console.

[image: image of finished test]

In the above image for example, I'd like to be able to reload the page without having the whole test re-run.

I'm sure other people out there have been looking for this as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My coworker found an easy way for me. Just have to `Right Click > Reload Frame`

[image: right click Reload Frame]

Whoohoo!

A much more cumbersome way that I found is to go to the chrome console, select Your App from the frame selector dropdown [image: frame selector]

And do a `location.reload()` in the console